# Sharepoint and ADL-DS

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ad-lds

Can I install SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2008 and using the Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (formerly ADAM) for Authentication and autorization?

Do I loose something in functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use AD LDS with SharePoint 2010. See here for further reference.
[AD LDS + SharePoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/bd5c7487-2f75-4229-a7d0-f5f8c2141de7/)

I don't know if you are lossing any functionality.