# Installing internet facing SharePoint 2010 with Active Directory Application Mode

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ad-lds

Are there any known issues installing an internet-facing SharePoint 2010 with Active Directory Lightweight Services or is it a logical choice?

Comment: Honestly, I'd say go for it. I don't see any outstanding issues with AD LDS. It's still not even a year old technology. I'm assuming they had integration with SP2010 in mind when deploying it.

Comment: also - http://serverfault.com/questions/222853/sharepoint-and-adl-ds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem using AD LDS for authentication with a internet facing SP2010 site. Consider using other AuthN methods such as LiveID or OpenID if you don't want to handle the user management yourself.